# AJAX POST to web api using Json - 500 internal server error

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to connect to a web api from client side using ajax jquery - POST method.
My code sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#btn392").click(function () {
    alert("test");
    var url = "https://test.ie/V2/Core/Sessions";

    var data = { AuthenticationProvider: 0 };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType:'jsonp',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        headers: { 'Pz-ApplicationName': 'xxxx', 'Pz-ApplicationKey': yyyy','Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'},
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        },

    });    

    });
});
</script>
```

**getting response as below:**

Request URL:

```
https://test.ie/V2/Core/Sessions?callback=jQuery18301695447497748852_1466229802951&{%22AuthenticationProvider%22:0}&_=1466230308713
```

**Request Method:GET

Status Code:500 Internal Server Error**
Remote Address:193.111.82.196:443

```
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type,Pz-Authorisation,X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:close
Content-Length:409

Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 18 Jun 2016 06:11:39 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5

X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
Request Headers

view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Host:pwpservice-qa.test.ie
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2770.0 Safari/537.36
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
callback:jQuery18301695447497748852_1466229802951
{"AuthenticationProvider":0}:
_:1466230308713
```

Eventhough I am trying to do a post it shows response a GET and throws internal server error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So if you have internal SERVER error, why are you giving us JS code?

Answer (score 0):

Like the message says, the error is happening on the server when it processes your request. The server logs are the best place to check to get more information about what is going on. If you have no access to them you can open the developer mode of your browser (they all have one) to debug the request(s) in their raw form.

Comment: Hi flup,Thanks very much for getting back to me. I checked server logs and could not find any information. Is there a possibility that the server which hosts api should authorize our ip?

Comment: It depends on the server code of course but response code 500 usually is used for server errors. So for example when the server code throws an exception while processing your request. If a firewall blocks your IP you're most likely to see your request time out. If the server refuses to serve your request because you lack permissions it will generally reply with a response code in the 400 range, not a 500.